# HoloLens device portal not available

Tags: usb, hololens

When connecting HoloLens via USB to my computer, the device portal is still not available after setting it up as explained in the [install tools page](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/holographic/install_the_tools).

All I get in the browser 127.0.0.1:10080 is the generic "*unable to connect*" page.

Is there any way to know what is failing? What could I check? Any tip will be appreciated!

EDIT: browsers used: Edge, Firefox and Chrome.

EDIT2: Hololens development mode is on.

Comment: What browser are you using? Also make sure that your HoloLens is on.

Comment: HoloLens are on, sure... and I tried with several browsers (Firefox, Chrome and Edge)

Comment: I guess you have to browser doesn't affect but my doubt is whether Developer mode is on in your HoloLens or not ? check this link - https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/holographic/using_the_windows_device_portal#setting_up_hololens_to_use_windows_device_portal

Comment: Yes, the development mode is on. I could solve the problem, not sure what exactly I installed because it is quite confusing, installing VS 2015 with the update 3 was not enough, and installing the emulator is a nightmare...

Answer (score 3):

Connecting over USB requires the PC be running IPoverUSB, which is installed with the Windows 10 SDK.  You can verify that it's running by checking the Services tab of Task Manager for IpOverUsbSvc.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, as commented above the problem solved somehow installing or re-installing VS2015 Update3 with all features or installing the Hololens Emulator (which failed 4 or 5 times). If some time this happens again, I know I have to look for this service.

Comment: It worked for me thanks!. IpOverUsbSvc was stopped, I just started it.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, another resolution to this issue may be the USB port you are using.
I initially was using a USB 3 port (which I've used to flash my HoloLens many times) and had the same issues.

On a whim, I switched to an older USB2 port and it's working perfectly now. SO try different USB ports if you are having this issue.